# Тело функции РЯД()в excel

Tags: excel

Функция y=ax+c, известно только (x) всех точек и сколько всего точек(1..890), в excel с помощью функции РЯД(x1..xn, 1..890) получаем (y) для каждой точки, а вот как реализовать это через программирование, где увидеть алгоритм(тело) функции РЯД, я в excel новичок.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: РЯД(x1..xn, 1..890) - в таком виде игреки здесь совсем не вычисленные по формуле, а просто последовательность 1..890. Excel по этой функции не вычисляет ничего, а просто отображает то, что задано. Вместо 1..890 нужно задать значения игреков, тогда диаграмма будет действительно показывать график функции игрек от икс.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то я не нашёл в Excel функцию РЯД.

Алгоритм(тело) функции `y=ax+c` - это `y = a * x + c`. Подставляете по очереди иксы, вычисляете и получаете соответствующие игреки. Называется затабулировать функцию.

Для этого в Excel берёте две колонки `A` и `B`, одну подписываете "Иксы" (ячейка `A1`), вторую "Игреки" (ячейка `B1`). В первую (начиная с `A2`) вводите заданные иксы. Если иксы заданы арифметической последовательностью, то вводите первое и второе значение, выделяете обе ячейки и протягиваете якорёк ячейки (правый нижний угол) вниз до последнего икса. В ячейке `B2` пишите формулу `=A2*a+c`, где вместо `a` и `c` нужно подставить заданные числа. Потом размножаете ячейку вниз (как иксы) до конца иксов. Готово!

После этого по этой таблице можно построить диаграмму.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *не нашёл в Excel функцию РЯД* - нет ее в перечне функций листа. Это функция для построения диаграмм (отображение рядов данных)